# How to take app list and app details from Google Play with using some APIs?

Tags: android, api, oauth

Now I was taking **app list and app details** from Google Play.

It's based on open source below.

> https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/.

Actually it worked well before a week but now all APIs in source code above are blocked.
I investigated source code and found "https:// www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", one of APIs returns "https:// developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps".

Because of this result, http:// android.clients.google.com/market/api/ApiRequest in android-market-api cannot be used anymore.

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCgMP.png)

Message says I have to migrate to OAuth 2.0 but there is no API for the same functions above.

Here is my questions.

1. Is there official APIs with OAuth 2.0 for the same function above ?
2. Is there alternative APIs or process for the same function above? (The best is finding a way to use android-market-api.)

I really have to resolve this issue. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: When was the last time you were able to use the market api with ClientLogin successfully?

Comment: https://42matters.com/api/ is this fine for you? As there is no any Official API you will always have to rely on this kind of third party API, the one you were using is Free and you can't blame them, so If you are ready to spend some money other options can be there for you to rely on. in base everyone is making there own custom search engine to look into playstore site. So if you can build one for yourself, you would be able to modify and stay updated yourself for sure.

Comment: You might be able to get away with scraping the website :) . It's pretty easy to do.